# Count and Stats api showing different doc's count in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

1)I have an index "data" which has  479427 documents in it. To get the count i had used `GET /data/_search`  i got response like this

```
"hits": {
    "total": 479427,
    "max_score": 1,
```

2)I checked using count api `GET /data/_count` and response i got is like this

```
{
  "count": 479427,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  }
}
```

FROM 1 and 2 the count of articles is same .

But when i tried `GET /data/_stats` command i am getting different counts in get and total fields.

```
"data": {
  "primaries": {
    "docs": {
      "count": 2407154,
      "deleted": 357392
    },
    "indexing": {
      "index_total": 4926760,
      "index_time_in_millis": 31181542,
      "index_current": 2744,
      "index_failed": 260136,
      "delete_total": 0,
      "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
      "delete_current": 0,
      "noop_update_total": 175,
      "is_throttled": false,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
    },
    "get": {
      "total": 4773829,
      "time_in_millis": 857412,
      "exists_total": 4773829,
      "exists_time_in_millis": 857412,
      "missing_total": 0,
      "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
      "current": 0
    },
    "merges": {
      "current": 0,
      "current_docs": 0,
      "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "total": 82217,
      "total_time_in_millis": 19552894,
      "total_docs": 87321796,
      "total_size_in_bytes": 281542406990,
      "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
      "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 488983,
      "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 35543080
    },
    "refresh": {
      "total": 956338,
      "total_time_in_millis": 29144660
    },
    "flush": {
      "total": 697,
      "total_time_in_millis": 469603
    },
    "segments": {
      "count": 114,
      "memory_in_bytes": 7145544,
      "terms_memory_in_bytes": 4862940,
      "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 1037064,
      "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
      "norms_memory_in_bytes": 116928,
      "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 1128612,
      "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 13753207,
      "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes": 548831232,
      "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 2182,
      "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 350648
    },
    "translog": {
      "operations": 19488,
      "size_in_bytes": 799972235
    },
    "suggest": {
      "total": 0,
      "time_in_millis": 0,
      "current": 0
    },
    "request_cache": {
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "evictions": 0,
      "hit_count": 0,
      "miss_count": 0
    },
    "recovery": {
      "current_as_source": 0,
      "current_as_target": 0,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 13306
    }
  },
  **"total": {
    "docs": {                >Here i am getting total docs count 4814308
      "count": 4814308,
      "deleted": 715540
    },**
    "store": {
      "size_in_bytes": 11910376476,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
    },
    "indexing": {
      "index_total": 9590499,
      "index_time_in_millis": 61324893,
      "index_current": 2744,
      "index_failed": 310323,
      "delete_total": 0,
      "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
      "delete_current": 0,
      "noop_update_total": 175,
      "is_throttled": false,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
    },
    "get": {
      "total": 4773829,
      "time_in_millis": 857412,
      "exists_total": 4773829,
      "exists_time_in_millis": 857412,
      "missing_total": 0,
      "missing_time_in_millis": 0,
      "current": 0
    },
    "search": {
      "open_contexts": 0,
      "query_total": 21901088,
      "query_time_in_millis": 11241895,
      "query_current": 0,
      "fetch_total": 4578094,
      "fetch_time_in_millis": 1774794,
      "fetch_current": 0,
      "scroll_total": 0,
      "scroll_time_in_millis": 0,
      "scroll_current": 0
    },
    "merges": {
      "current": 0,
      "current_docs": 0,
      "current_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "total": 153172,
      "total_time_in_millis": 37586865,
      "total_docs": 170014671,
      "total_size_in_bytes": 542992816504,
      "total_stopped_time_in_millis": 0,
      "total_throttled_time_in_millis": 920242,
      "total_auto_throttle_in_bytes": 71693630
    },
    "refresh": {
      "total": 1841635,
      "total_time_in_millis": 56292736
    },
    "flush": {
      "total": 1343,
      "total_time_in_millis": 946306
    },
    "warmer": {
      "current": 0,
      "total": 3822250,
      "total_time_in_millis": 1098530
    },
    "query_cache": {
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 2706088,
      "total_count": 20222398,
      "hit_count": 4846746,
      "miss_count": 15375652,
      "cache_size": 271,
      "cache_count": 2267,
      "evictions": 1996
    },
    "fielddata": {
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "evictions": 0
    },
    "percolate": {
      "total": 0,
      "time_in_millis": 0,
      "current": 0,
      "memory_size_in_bytes": -1,
      "memory_size": "-1b",
      "queries": 0
    },
    "completion": {
      "size_in_bytes": 0
    },
    "segments": {
      "count": 229,
      "memory_in_bytes": 14245875,
      "terms_memory_in_bytes": 9804839,
      "stored_fields_memory_in_bytes": 2068360,
      "term_vectors_memory_in_bytes": 0,
      "norms_memory_in_bytes": 234752,
      "doc_values_memory_in_bytes": 2137924,
      "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 25849179,
      "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes": 1097662464,
      "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 4364,
      "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 701360
    },
    "translog": {
      "operations": 39262,
      "size_in_bytes": 1616348491
    },
    "suggest": {
      "total": 0,
      "time_in_millis": 0,
      "current": 0
    },
    "request_cache": {
      "memory_size_in_bytes": 0,
      "evictions": 0,
      "hit_count": 0,
      "miss_count": 0
    },
    "recovery": {
      "current_as_source": 0,
      "current_as_target": 0,
      "throttle_time_in_millis": 32764
    }
  }
}
```

I even checked the same in curator by giving `curator_cli show_indices --verbose` which given response like this:

`data      open   11.1GB   4814308   5   1 2017-05-31T13:00:37Z`

Why there is difference ?

Update ----------------------

1)You mean stats API considers each field in nested as a document right? 
Note:`BTW I am talking about the total.docs.count field in stats api`.
2)Where as count API will give the count of documents that are present in the index based on unique id.

So My question is if i want to know how many documents are present inside the index which api gives the right count whether `count`,`get`,`stats`  or `curator_cli show_indices --verbose`(using curator) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the stats API includes so called `nested` documents, as fields, which are marked as `nested` in the mapping are counted as own lucene documents, where as the count API is just counting the top level objects.